# React-images-loaded only fires done event once despite content changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a React component where I have a image display on the left side and a list of image names on the right side. Here's a simplified version of how I do it:

```
const Display = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState("1.jpg");

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="display loading">
                <ImagesLoaded
                    done={(e) => {
                        e.elements[0].parentNode.classList.remove("loading");
                    }}
                >
                    <img src={`http://localhost:8080/${image}`} alt={image} />
                </ImagesLoaded>
                <div className="loader"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="list">
                <li onClick={setImage("1.jpg")}>Image 1</li>
                <li onClick={setImage("2.jpg")}>Image 2</li>
                <li onClick={setImage("3.jpg")}>Image 3</li>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

I have some css set up so the `div.loader` would show some animation when `div.display` has `.loading` class. This works on first load, after image is completely loaded, the `.loading` class will be removed. However, when image is changed by `image` state, `ImagesLoaded` component does not seem to be completely re-rendered, as in it does not execute the `done` event again, so the `div.display` is forever stuck with the `loading` class.

I tried using another library called `react-on-images-loaded`, but it did the exact same thing. Is there something I'm not understanding right about the React rendering system? If so, how can I get the desired effect? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use onLoad event of the image and why are you trying to manipulate DOM elements instead of generating jsx from state?

You can add state loading that is set to true when image changes and set to false when onLoad event triggered. Set your css according to the loading state:

```
const Display = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('1.jpg');
  //loading state
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  //when image loaded set loading to false
  const onImageLoad = useCallback((e) => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);
  //when image changes set loading to true
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
  }, [image]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        // set class based on loading state
        className={`display ${loading ? 'loading' : ''}`}
      >
        <img
          src={`/${image}`}
          alt={image}
          // onload change loading
          onLoad={onImageLoad}
        />
        <div className="loader"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="list">
        {/* you were not passing a function to onClick */}
        <li onClick={() => setImage('1.jpg')}>Image 1</li>
        <li onClick={() => setImage('2.jpg')}>Image 2</li>
        <li onClick={() => setImage('3.jpg')}>Image 3</li>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Tip to test in Chrome dev tools: go to network tab there is a dropdown that says "online" click "Add..." click "Add new profile" and give it a 1000 latency. Now when you use that profile things will load fast but will wait for 1 second before loading.

Comment: This works perfectly! I was caught in a fixed way of thinking and could not break through. Your approach not only solved my problem but also made me understand better the whole react philosophy. A thousand thanks!